# Chakra UI createIcon() throws "Invalid hook call" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, icons, chakra-ui

I have created my own custom **React.js Icons** package, with the help of the `@chakra-ui/react` and `@chakra-ui/icons` packages. However, when I import an Icon from my custom package, **create-react-app** throws an `Invalid hook call`.

Here is the code:

My custom package:

```
export const Down = createIcon({ d: "M21 7l-9 10L3 7", displayName: "hey" });
```

The other project I import it into:

```
import { Down } from "@hashtag-design-system/icons";

...

return (
    <Down />
)
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: I've seen many things similar to do with importing your own package, I fixed this myself with `npm link <project dir>` from the root of the icons package but this isn't ideal

Comment: Oh, yes. I fixed it eventually, but I should probably post the answer

Answer (score -1):

I had to pass `@chakra-ui/react` & `@chakra-ui/icons`, as `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` file, in order to fit this. I also used Rollup.js, that did not include extra code, but adding the packages as peerDependencies, seem to solve the issue